# Mysql query statement to find how many time I am the max amount for a listing

Tags: mysql

Here is my tabel structure.

```
id
veh_id
user_id
amount
...
```

I have other tables to relate the user_id and veh_id as well.

I want to know how many times a user has put an amount on each veh_id and on how many occasions, this amount is actually the highest amount received.  I would like to have those 2 counts for each user available.

```
id, veh_id, user_id, amount
1    1       30        100
2    1       32        105
3    2       30        100
4    2       32        95
5    2       33        90
```

I would like the select statement to give me:

> user 30 as bid 2 times and 1 time is the higest bidder
>
> user 32 as bid 2 time ans 1 time is the higest bidder
>
> user 33 bid 1 time and 0 time the highest bidder

I don't know if it is possible to get those numbers.

Comment: definitely you will get answer from SO experts. But it is still best to show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Is id increment representative of the order in which rows were added?  (ie: 1 was the first row, 2 the second row and so on?  I ask because the amounts seem to go down not up over time...)

Comment: yes, Id are incremental.  but one can place a bid lower that another one with a id bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *might* be close, not sure exactly how you're relating vehicles together.

```
select
  user_id,
  count(*) as num_bids,
  SUM(is_highest) as max_bids
from ( select
  a.user_id,
  COALESCE((select
      MAX(b.amount) < a.amount
    from bid as b
    where b.id < a.id
    and b.veh_id=a.veh_id
  ), 1) as is_highest
from bid as a
) as c
group by user_id
```

My understanding is user 30 has 2 max bids (2 first bids on a vehicle).

**EDIT:** If you're just looking for total 1 max bid per vehicle, let me know.  That's actually a lot easier than rolling back to see who's bids were max when they came in...

**EDIT2:** Solution for only 1 max counts per vehicle:

Seems like this should be simpler for some reason:

```
select
 user_id,
 count(*) as num_bids,
 count(vamt) as num_max
from bid
left join (
  select veh_id as vid, max(amount) as vamt
  from bid
  group by veh_id
) as a on vid = veh_id and vamt <= amount
group by user_id
```

Comment: Yes, I am looking for only 1 max bid per veh.

Comment: I would like to add a WHERE Clause in there, so I put WHERE in front of  GROUPP BY and in my WHERE clause, I am refering to another table so I put a LEFT JOIN TABLE as e  and in the WHERE' I wrote WHERE e.cid=3 .  I was expecting a result, but no, I come out empty.  Basically, I want all the vehicle that belongs to a certain dealership(e.cid)

Comment: The new table related to the bid with the bid.veh_id = e.id

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select x.user_id, x.bid_times, COALESCE(y.max_times,0) as max_times from
(select user_id, count(*) as bid_times from testt group by user_id) as x
 LEFT JOIN
(select user_id, count(*) as max_times  from testt a where 0=( select count(*) from testt where amount > a.amount and veh_id=a.veh_id ) group by user_id) as y
ON x.user_id=y.user_id
```